# Embolden "asked" and "viewed", not their values, and make "active" look like a link

Tags: feature-request, design, user-experience

In the sidebar of questions, there's a block displaying when was the question asked and viewed and how many time it was viewed:

[image]

What I propose is to make the field **names** bold instead of the field values, like this:

[image]

Why I want this is because when a human is searching for "asked", he wants to see "asked" on the page, and will skip all the text that doesn't look like "asked", but now, "asked" looks like all other text on the page, so it will likely get skipped too, and the user won't find "asked" quickly.

But bold text stands out and attracts attention, so the user will see "asked" even if he doesn't want to, so he will know where to find when the question was asked.

"Today" and "N times" mean nothing to the user unless he already knows that the question was asked today and was viewed N times.

Other parts of the site, such as "how to edit" and "how to format", have correct emboldening.

If you do what I propose, the "tagged" text should be emboldened too, because it's in the same block and looks exactly like "asked", "viewed" and "active".

Another thing about this block is that the "active" link doesn't look like a link. It should be underlined. "Similar question" has underlining, so it will not be off-place on the site.

Comment: completely agree ...